# Find best (most efficient) combination of Ingredients

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, optimization

#### Question:

Suggest me an approach to that kind of problem. Is it pure optimization problem?
What might Machine Learning techniques can be helpful here?

#### Case Study

My reduced case study is as follows:

> I have 3 types of ingredients (A, B, C). In each experiment, some
> combination from the ingredients is chosen and applied on something.
> Result can be **1:poor**, **2:middle**, **3:high**.

#### Example:

```
| Input      | Output      |
|:----------:|:-----------:|
| A          |       2     | 
| AB         |       1     |   
| ABC        |       2     | 
| BC         |       3     | 
| C          |       2     | 
|...         |      ...    |
```

I need to find out what is the winning combination of ingredients according to the results.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be more detailed in your question. It is not clear as to what A,B and C are? Are they just ingredients? Or are they some kind of functions or something of that sort?

Comment: A B C are just ingredients which applied in form of a spray on the field.
As a result, there are a grades for their efficiency vs prsts. So, the combination of AB for example may give grade 3, but after certain number of experiences, the same combination AB might give grade 2
So, assume that you have many experiments with different combinations of letters (ingredients), sometimes it might be only one ingredient. And each time the same combination might give a slightly different result

Comment: This is a multiple (multi-variable) ordinal regression problem, as far as I can tell. Hopefully this knowledge will give you enough information to allow you to help yourself.

Comment: @Emre I dont think it should be seen that way. The goal is not to predict the value of a new combination but finding the optimal combination according to an output. A classic optimization problem.

Comment: That would make it an argmax of the regressor, no? You still need the regressor.

Comment: I would say the Regressor need an optimizer ;) So one step is being done unnecessarily ... you are finding a general model while a stochastic search does the job. For instance consider TSP problem. That is the same thing. A sequence of nodes in a graph which optimizes an output (the distance to traverse). Why would you find a model to describe all shortest paths possible? TSP is an optimization problem and a typical example usage for GA.

Comment: Because I assume there is noise. If a given input always leads to a given output you would be right.

Comment: If there is noise then you are certainly right. I did not see the comment above then. I wrote the opt answer as he mentioned again but your comment is also a proper approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimization problem and optimization is all what Machine Learning does in classic sense (mostly not unsupervised approaches).

Your problem can be designed to be solved by Genetic Algorithms. For this you need to make a sequences of ingrediants which is called chromosome (genetic representation of solution) and an objective function which is to be minimized/maximized according to the chromosomes (it's usually called fitness function and is to be maximized then).

You have genetic operators to be applied randomly on your chromosomes:

1. **Reproduction**: 2 parent chromosomes result in two children.
2. **Mutation**: One single bit (one of ingrediants) is randomly chosen to
   be switched with another one (like in a genetically normal family, a
   baby is born with a genetic phenomenon).
3. **Natural Selection**: Uncle Darwin believed that nature "keeps the best
   and  discards the rest". But who is the best? Well, you already have a fitness function!

Continue till you reach the optimum and select the best chromosome.

Of course it was the intuitive explanation of this beautiful idea. See more [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/institute-for-data-systems-and-society/ids-338j-multidisciplinary-system-design-optimization-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MITESD_77S10_lec11.pdf) and if you needed implementation details please drop a comment here.

Good Luck.

## Update: More Details

I have an optimization problem which is too complex or large to be solved analytically so I need a heuristic method to approximate the optimal solution. For instance each subset of $28$ ingredients outputs a result $y$ where $y \in [0,100]$ (it's much bigger than your sample problem just to use optimization properly).

1. **Initialization:** Randomly produce $n$ combinations of material as initial population. Choose probabilities $P_{crossover}=0.25$, $P_{mutation}=0.01$ and $n_{selection}=250$ (values are just examples)
2. **Evaluation of Fitness:** Evaluate the output for each of them

> ```
> | input         | output 
> | ------------- |:-------------:|
> | ABCDEFGH      | 23.5          |
> | BDCGTRFJ      | 45.6          |
> | ZHTRFGOIUPOIZ | 18.3          |
> | ...           | ...           |
> ```

3. Choose top $n_{selection}$ and ignore the rest. If you found an optimal solution (in your case you said output=3 is desired) stop, if not:
4. According to $P_{crossover}$ choose 25% of survived samples and reproduce children by combining them through a breaking point (image from [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm))).

[image]

For instance if $ABCDEFGH$ and $BCDEFGHJ$ are survived, then choose a breaking point and exchange their parts (the image is 2-point crossover. You may apply 1-point crossover. It's all about the variations of the same concept). Technically the crossover point should be also determined probabilistically but I just skipped it. Break them from wherever you want! Here we choose $3^{rd}$ gene for this so $ABCDEFGH$ and $BCDEFGHJ$ will become $ABDEFGHJ$ and $BCCDEFGH$. Two children out of two parents. Apply it on all chosen survived samples.

5. According to $P_{mutation}$ choose 1% of survived samples and randomly(again, technically with a predefined probability) change one material in it (technically the samples are usually binary so you flip between $0$ and $1$. Here as you have nominal variables you need to change the variable). Let's say in survived sample $FVBGTZHU$ I randomly choose $V$ and exchange it with $P$ so I get $FPBGTZHU$.
6. Now the new generation is born (keep it as the same size of the original population for better structure). Go back to 2 and continue till you find your answer.

For different variations of GA (Elitism, Island Model, etc.) see the literature for [Evolutionary Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) e.g. [this one](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub2/baluja_shumeet_1995_1/baluja_shumeet_1995_1.pdf).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please bring me a numerical example. Suppose there are A x 20 times with grade 2; A x 30 times with grade 3; AB x 20 times with grade 2; AC x 15 times with grade 1; ABC x 10 times with grade 2; ABC x 10 times with grade 3; C x 25 times with grade 2. THANKS

Comment: Sure ... will update the answer

Comment: How do you calculate output for the new untested samples (children)?